# Weird control sequence before password prompt

Tags: debian, terminal

I have installed debian 8 with xfce4 - freshly - and everything seems to work fine, except:

When I try to enter some password into the xfce4-terminal there **sometimes** is displayed some weird escape sequence (`^[[3~`) in front of the prompt:

```
user@debian:~$ su
^[[3~Password:
```

This prevents me most of the time to enter the password correctly. When I delete the prompt with the backspace and then enter my password it seems to work.

So there seems to be written some weird stuff to the console.

I tried to search for the control sequence, but did not find it anywhere. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you press something in between `su` and typing password?

Comment: No, I didn't press anything.

Comment: The key combination `^[[3~` is typically associated with the DELETE key.

Answer (score 1):

On a typical PC keyboard, there are three candidates for *"delete"* (considering that many people *equate* this with *"backspace"*).

Here is a typical example

[image]

The <kbd>backspace</kbd> key (above <kbd>enter</kbd>) *may* send ASCII backspace or delete (`BS` or `DEL`), which is a single byte.  The <kbd>Delete</kbd> key off to the right (under <kbd>Insert</kbd> *may* send an escape sequence, which you would see echoed as `^[[3~`.

That is, they *may*.  It really depends upon the way the host interprets these.  A while back, I found that SCO would send an `ASCII DEL` for the second of these.  Ultimately since you're probably using a terminal *emulator*, it is that program which decides what characters it will read for a given key *symbol*.

But unless you've done something interesting with `xmodmap`, the odds are that you'll see the escape sequence echoed for that key.

The third key, at the lower right, is <kbd>Del</kbd>, which some people also equate with *delete*.  For that, you might see `^[On`, or you might simply see <kbd>.</kbd> (see *[What's the meaning of a message consisting only of a dot?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/300419/whats-the-meaning-of-a-message-consisting-only-of-a-dot/300426)* and the mention of Kurt Vonnegut for further reading).