# What does an application read when the user press a backspace in the terminal in raw mode?

Tags: terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, input, control-characters

In raw mode, if you type a character in the terminal, the application on the other side will read the ASCII code for the typed character.

But what about when you press the backspace key in the terminal, what would  the application on the other side read?

Comment: Why don't you write a program to test it and find out?

Comment: @StephenHarris Probably because whatever happens on her/his computer is not necessarily universal. E.g. on some systems it might be `^H` (0x08) whereas on others `DEL` (0x7F).

Comment: `showkey -a` ... in a terminal set to send a delete will display `0x7F` for `backspace`... but `CTRL backspace` will display 0x08 ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to allow backspaces in unbuffered/non-canonical mode?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/382790/how-to-allow-backspaces-in-unbuffered-non-canonical-mode)

Comment: @JdeBP This may be a duplicate, but not of that question. Here the question isn't about ^H vs ^? but about what the effect of the backspace key is — “it sends a control character” is the short answer here.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, if you type a character in a terminal, the application will read that character.

Well, more precisely, if you type a character in a terminal, it's converted to one or more bytes — most modern Unix system use the [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoding of characters. The application reads those bytes and reassembles the characters. This is still not ASCII codes — ASCII is a 7-bit encoding, so all characters in the ASCII character set fit in one byte.

When you type a function or cursor key such as <kbd>BackSpace</kbd>, <kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Return</kbd>, <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>Left</kbd>, etc., it's encoded as a [control character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character) or an [escape sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequence). There are a few control characters that correspond to function keys, such as ^I (byte value 9) for <kbd>Tab</kbd> and ^M (byte value 13) for <kbd>Return</kbd>. Most other function keys send an escape sequence beginning with the escape character (^[, byte value 27).

<kbd>BackSpace</kbd> sends a control character. For historical reasons, which control character it sends depends on the terminal and on its configuration: it can be either ^H (byte value 8) or ^? (byte value 127). On many modern terminals, you can change this in the configuration; see [How to allow backspaces in unbuffered/non-canonical mode?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/382790/how-to-allow-backspaces-in-unbuffered-non-canonical-mode). In case the setting isn't picked up automatically, you can declare it with `stty`.

For more background, see [How do keyboard input and text output work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116629/how-do-keyboard-input-and-text-output-work/116630#116630) and [How to make a comprehensive set of possibilities for defining GNU-screen "command characters"?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/244933/how-to-make-a-comprehensive-set-of-possibilities-for-defining-gnu-screen-comman/245305#245305)

Comment: No, `stty` is not how one changes the terminal's behaviour.  See my answer to the duplicate question, where this has already been answered including the correct way, for only some terminals, that one can change what the key sends.

Comment: `stty erase` is to tell the line discipline which character is sent by your terminal upon the Backspace key. However, the line discipline doesn't use that information when in _raw_ mode. That information is used to implement the LD's line editor (whereby upon receiving that character, it removes the last character from the line buffer as opposed to adding the ^H/^? to that edit line buffer, and the content of that buffer made available for reading by the application when ^J, eof, eol, eol2 characters are received).